# Adding Columns programmatically to listview in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

How can I add columns programmatically to a listview?

Answer (score 30):

Set the listView.View as such:

```
GridView myGridView = new GridView();
myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = true; 
myGridView.ColumnHeaderToolTip = "Employee Information";

GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("FirstName");
gvc1.Header = "FirstName";
gvc1.Width = 100;
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc1);
GridViewColumn gvc2 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc2.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("LastName");
gvc2.Header = "Last Name";
gvc2.Width = 100;
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc2);
GridViewColumn gvc3 = new GridViewColumn();
gvc3.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("EmployeeNumber");
gvc3.Header = "Employee No.";
gvc3.Width = 100;
myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc3);

listView.View = myGridView;
```

Comment: where can i find complete example about adding Col data also.this code only adds (First Name,Last Name,Employee No.) headers...i need data also please ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this;

```
GridView _gridView = new GridView();
_gridView.Columns.Add(
    new GridViewColumn 
    {
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("columnTitle"), 
        Header = "columnHeader", 
        Width = double.NaN 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            for(int i=0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
                    gvc.Header = "Column"+i;
                    gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("column"+i);
                    lvgvc.Columns.Add(gvc);
                }
```