# WPF: Is it possible to create a number of ListView.View templates and dynamically select one at run-time?

Tags: wpf, templates, listview, gridview

I want to have `ListView` control which can be filled with one of a number of different object types (not mixed, always just one type). I would like to adjust the columns dynamically to correspond to the object type currently in the list.

I know I could do this programmatically ([Adding Columns programatically to listview in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868204/adding-columns-programatically-to-listview-in-wpf)) but I was wondering if I could define the different column descriptions (`GridView`s) in XAML as resources and then select the one I need at run-time when the object type changes?

**Clarification**
I am using a `ListView` control which displays details in columns. The columns are defined like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="TheList">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Columns" Width="80"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Added" Width="80"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Automatically" Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

My question is: can I define a number of `ListView.View` sections and switch between them depending of the object type in the list? The list will only contain one type of object at one time. I just need to display a different set of attributes.

The replies I have received so far seem to assume that I have a simple list which contains a mixture of objects. That is not the case. What I am looking for is something like this:

```
Name        Address      Town
-----------------------------------------
Liz         Buck House   London
Angie       Block House  Berlin
```

and then to switch to something completely different:

```
Town       Population
------------------------------
London     123456
Swansea    65432
```

Perhaps I'm making this too complicated....

Answer (score 2):

First, define a DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyListTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock FontSize="14" Foreground="Black" Name="tbNombre" Padding="5">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <Binding Path="Nombre"></Binding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}"
                            Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="tbNombre" Property="Foreground" Value="Silver" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

After that, change the data template dynamically:

```
Dim template As DataTemplate = Application.Current.Resources("MyListTemplate")
MyList.ItemTemplate = template
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're selecting a template based on they type of the object then you can just set the `DataType` property of the template to that object. Then WPF will select the template that matches the type of the item.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:MyType}"> ...
```

If you want to select a template based on some property within the type, a DataTemplateSelector is probably better.

See [Bea Stollnitz's blog](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=16) for more info.