# Windows form code pass to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

i am trying to make a Column header in WPF by using code like this

```
listview.Columns.Add("Name",100);
listview.View = View.Details;
listview.FullrowSelect = true;
listview.GridLines = True;
```

and the error is always saying that i need System.windows.Controls.Listview but when i added the class using System.Windows.Controls.Listview; it's the same error

Comment: Did you instantiate `ListView`?  Please post the exact exception text.

Comment: listview is the name of my ListView dragged in the design form.

Comment: Okay.  Please post the exact exception you're getting, since what you've posted is unlikely to be the text of what VS is showing.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'SubItems' and no extension method 'SubItems' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Tommo\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Morning\Morning\MainWindow.xaml.cs 185 34 Morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look here, I think this is something that you are trying to achieve.

[Adding Columns programatically to listview in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868204/adding-columns-programatically-to-listview-in-wpf)

Comment: GridView has columns, ListView does not. For more clarity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953503/missing-listview-columns-in-wpf and this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that WPF use Presentation DLL to construct UI while normal windows from use System.Windows.Forms. As a result, you can't use the Win Form' s control in WPF, you can use gridview instead, please refer to Moeen' s link